# SQL Query conditional row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'list' that is like this:

```
system  item1  exception
------------------------
A       John   1
A       Sarah  0
A       Tim    1
A       Blake  0
B       Nikki  1
B       Rick   0
C       Jimbo  1
```

I am trying to build a query and I'm so terrible at it and I'm stuck. I want to return all rows unconditionally UNLESS system = 'A'. If system = 'A' then only return the rows where exception is true.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you should play around with different `where` clauses until you figure out the logic.  It isn't that hard.

Comment: I have been. Your comment isn't helpful

Comment: If you have been post up your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE system != 'A' OR exception = 1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e41d6/2)

Comment: Thanks lpg for your help. Very simple solution

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from list
 where (system = 'A' and exception = 1)
    or system <> 'A'
```

You can group conditions in the WHERE clause by enclosing each block in ()

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php

Comment: Thanks Brian for your time. There is a slight mistake in the last line, it should be "or system <> 'A'"